# Angular app will not update web page after edit

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, npm

Running "ng serve" in WSL2 window (Ubuntu) on Win10 host.  Opened localhost:4200 in browser.  Edited app.component.html and saved.  Page in browser is SUPPOSED to update, but doesn't.  In fact, I can't even force it to refresh to new content, old content seems to be cached somewhere.  Anybody have a suggestion?  BTW, (mis)behaves identically with Chrome or Microsoft Edge browsers.

Comment: When you run ng serve, do you see the app rebuilding in the console?

Comment: Known issues with WSL, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739